# Multiple, nested tax_query relation

Tags: tax-query

I have been stuck on a particular problem for a while now and have yet to find a way around it. I have custom widgets and for each widget I have added the ability to filter posts based on category AND/OR tags (this functionality works). I am now trying to expand on that by including in each widget a custom field where you can enter the ID of a category you wish to exclude (the custom field is already in the widget and stores user input).

Let me show you what I have so far to help understand:

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => $num_posts,
            'cat'               => -5,
            'tax_query'         => array(
                'relation'      => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                    'field'     => 'id',
                    'terms'     => $category,
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
                    'field'     => 'id',
                    'terms'     => $tags
                ),
            ),
            'offset'            => 1,
        );
```

As you can see I am taking in two arrays of input for both $category and $tags (this is working fine), but what does not seem to be working is:

```
'cat'               => -5,
```

If I remove the tax_query array completely, the exclude category works perfectly fine, so it appears that tax_query is overriding the exclude?

If someone could point me in the right direct, that would be great :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cat`-parameter is not overwritten by `tax_query`. Instead, it is added to `tax_query`. Thus, using `'cat' => -5`, the following array is appended to `tax_query`:

```
(
    [taxonomy] => category
    [terms] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [include_children] => 1
    [field] => term_id
    [operator] => NOT IN
)
```

The resulting taxonomy query is built up of three different clauses with the OR-operator. Thus, in your case, adding `'cat' => -5` simply adds the array described above to `tax_query`, resulting in the query returning that posts that are either

- not in category 5,
- in any of the categories in `$category`, or
- in any of the tags in `$tags`

### Nested tax_query

There is no way to use nested conditionals in `tax_query`. To achieve the conditional you are looking for (posts in a category from `$category` or having a tag from `tags`, but in all cases not being in category 5), you would have to hook into [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) and possibly [`posts_join`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join).

For anyone interested, the same goes for `meta_query`: this does not support nested queries either.

**EDIT**

### Using `posts_where`

In response to your comment: to achieve this using `posts_where`, you will want to apply the filter to just the one query for which you want to exclude a category. To do so, add the filter before creating your query, and remove it afterwards:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'myplugin_posts_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'myplugin_posts_where' );
```

**EDIT**

### Constructing the additional `WHERE`-clause

Using [`get_tax_sql`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tax_sql) to construct the additional `WHERE`-clause is useful as you do not have to construct your SQL manually, and the term IDs are automatically converted to term-taxonomy IDs.

```
$clauses = get_tax_sql( array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 2,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
), $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

$where .= $clauses['where'];
```

Comment: Thanks @engelen ! Using your suggestion I created a function with posts_where and when I print out the Query I can see my custom inclusion, but on the Front-end nothing displays. The page appears to stop loading other areas as well.

`function restrict_post_by_id( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;
 
    $where .= " AND (
db_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} WHERE term_taxonomy_id=5)";
    return $where;
}
   
add_filter( "posts_where" , "restrict_post_by_id" );`

Comment: First of all, the `posts_where` filter is applied to all WordPress post queries (`WP_Query`) that do not explicitly suppress filtering. There are two arguments passed to `posts_where`: `$where`, the `WHERE`-clause, and `$query`, the `WP_Query` instance for which the clause is being filtered. You will want to build a check to make sure the `WHERE`-clause is only altered for your specific query.

It might be a good idea to output the actual query (`print_r( new WP_Query( $args ) );`) to gain some insight in the query generated.

Comment: How am I able to determine the current query, or pass the specific query to the filter. Basically every widget has a custom field to enter an ID to exclude. Each one of those widgets has a new WP_Query object (with a different name of course) and multiple widgets with will appear on the same page. For example, you might have one widget excluding Category ID 5, but another on the same page excluding Tag ID 32.

I can't quite wrap my head around this.

Comment: You could add the filter right before starting the query and remove it after the query is executed, thus making sure it only applies to that specific query. I will update my answer to include example code for this.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include example code for this.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I had in my code trying to accomplish, but it wasn't working so I thought there was another way. Currently my setup looks like your updated answer. This part of the Query is getting added onto the end of the original Query, but posts are still displaying when they shouldn't. `$where .= " AND db_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} WHERE term_taxonomy_id=34 )";`

The posts I am trying to exclude belong to multiple taxonomies (multiple cat and tags) when I am only excluding 1 Taxonomy term ID. Does this call for a JOIN?

Comment: You're `db_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id` instead of `wp_posts.ID`. I suggest you use [get_tax_sql](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tax_sql) so you don't have to write your own raw `WHERE`-clause. See my updated answer for the way to use this function.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. These custom taxonomy queries are still relatively new to me. You are a god among men and I can't thank you enough for helping me through this. Definitely the best answer out there and will be beneficial to others.

Comment: I believe this answer is out of date. It looks like Wordpress Core can handle nested taxonomies. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29738

Answer (score 9):

Just providing an updated answer about Nested Taxonomies because they are indeed supported. The selected answer above is out of date / a little misleading. WordPress Core has supported [Nested Taxonomies since v4.1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29738)

**Taken from the WordPress Codex**

> The 'tax_query' clauses can be nested, to create more complex queries.
>   Example: Display posts that are in the quotes category OR both have
>   the quote post format AND are in the wisdom category:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'quotes' ),
        ),
        array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote' ),
                        ),
                        array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => array( 'wisdom' ),
                        ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: I am glad I scrolled down to read this. Thank you.